# Froala with ejs does not dissolve tags

Tags: node.js, ejs, froala

I want to use an rich-text editor inside node. Now i have froala and I can edit text inside a textarea. But if I want to display with ejs `<div><%= post.bio %></div>` its not encoded. it looks like `<p style="text-align: left;">Viele bekannte K&uuml;nstler verneigen sich ehrf&uuml;rchtig vor der Arbeit von Johannes Gr&uuml;tzke. Er ist f&uuml;r sie Vorbild, Vorreiter und einfach der genialste Maler mit unverwechselbarer Sicherheit in der Pinself&uuml;hrung` (its german text). So all tag are shown i the text. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because when you use `<%= %>` you have escaped from html tags. Try to use `<%- %>` when you want to display html output.